# Why is register not called when I blender version is set to 2.78 in my bl_info?

Tags: python, add-on

I noticed that Blender doesn't call `register()` on my addon when my `bl_info` specifies `"blender" : (2, 78, 0)`, but if I change to `(2, 80, 0)`, then `register()` is called.

Here is a minimal version of the `__init__.py`:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Str Test Add-on",
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > MelPropHelper",
    # "blender": (2, 80, 0), # toggle un-comment and blender does call register()
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "category": "3D View", 
}

def register():
    print(F"welcome to register") # will not print when 2, 78 is specified
 
def unregister():
    print(F"welcome to unregister") # will not print when 2, 78 is specified
```

Here's a sample output to the console with 2, 78:

```
Modules Installed (stripped-addon) from 'E:\\temp\\ble-zip-import-test\\bb_zip_import_me\\bb72.zip' into 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons'
```

And after clicking the check box

```
module changed on disk: 'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\stripped-addon\\__init__.py' reloading...
```

And after unclicking the check box:

```
addon_utils.disable: stripped-addon not loaded
```

Here's the output with 2,80

```
Modules Installed (stripped-addon) from 'E:\\temp\\ble-zip-import-test\\bb_zip_import_me\\bb72.zip' into 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons'
```

After clicking the check box

```
module changed on disk: 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\stripped-addon\\__init__.py' reloading...
welcome to register bb
```

After unclicking the check box

```
welcome to unregister
```

Tested on Blender 3.2.1
Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly why, but I have a hunch that it's probably because of the several API "breaking" changes and compatibility handling that are done since 2.80.

When 2.80 came out, all addons *had to be updated* to the new API to even be allowed to run.

See in [Reference/Release Notes/2.80/Python API/Addons - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) we can read:

> Make sure the `"blender"` key in the `bl_info` dictionary is set to:
> `(2, 80, 0)` not `(2, 8, 0)` or `(2, 79, 0)`
>
> Example: `"blender": (2, 80, 0),`
>
> Otherwise, this error is reported:
>
> `Exception: Add-on 'ADDON_NAME' has not been upgraded to 2.8, ignoring`

I guess you would have that issue with any version number prior to 2.80.0.

The page details other things that changed from v2.80, like registration. But overall, many breaking changes happened in the API since 2.80, and can happen at any new version. So I wouldn't expect to be able to make a 2.78 addon that works in newer versions. Nor would I expect to make an addon using v3.2's API that works with 2.78.

### Keeping track of API changes

I'll just quote [this post from testure](https://blenderartists.org/t/bpy-changes-should-i-have-known/1446348/3?u=l0lock):

> The most recent Python API changes are always listed in the api documentation, and are generated automatically:
> https://docs.blender.org/api/current/change_log.html
>
> A historical record of changes can be found on the wiki, but since these are hand-made docs there’s more chance for something not making it into the notes: [Reference/Release Notes - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes)
>
> That said, it’s worth noting that 2.93.6 to 3.3.1 is a pretty big jump- any time you wait this long to update your scripts you should expect there to be a lot of breaking changes that will need to be updated. So many versions have passed that it would be a pretty difficult task to track down each version that changed it, etc.